# Save multiple fields using ACF in Woocommerce(cart, checkout, order details)

Tags: woocommerce, product, advanced-custom-fields

I'm setting up ACF for selecting options in single product page. I already added the custom fields in single product page. How can I save multiple fields?
This code is working, but I need to save multiple fields like on the added field option-color.

```
/** Output custom fields field. */
function product_options_output_field() {
    $html = "";
    if( have_rows('select_options') ):
        $html .= "<div class='select-options'>";
        $html .= "<h4>Select Options</h4>";
        $html .= "<select class='option-multi-trip-one-way' id='option-multi-trip-one-way' name='option-multi-trip-one-way'>";
        $html .= "<option value='N/A'>Multi-trip/One-way **</option>";
        while( have_rows('select_options') ) : the_row();

            $multi_trip = get_sub_field('multi-tripone-way');
            $html .= "<option value=".$multi_trip.">".$multi_trip."</option>";

    endwhile;
    $html .= "</select>";
    $html .= "<br/>";
    $html .= "<select class='option-color' id='option-color' name='option-color'>";
    $html .= "<option value='N/A'>Color</option>";
        while( have_rows('select_options') ) : the_row();

            $color = get_sub_field('color');
            $html .= "<option value=".$color.">".$color."</option>";
        endwhile;
    $html .= "</select>";
    $html .= "</div>"; 
    endif;
    echo $html;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'product_options_output_field', 10 );


/** Add custom fields to cart item. */
function product_options_add_to_cart_item( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {
    $option_multi_trip_one_way = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'option-multi-trip-one-way');
    if ( empty( $option_multi_trip_one_way ) ) {
        return $cart_item_data;
    }
    $cart_item_data['option-multi-trip-one-way'] = $option_multi_trip_one_way;
    return $cart_item_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'product_options_add_to_cart_item', 10, 3 );

/**Display custom fields in the cart. */
function product_options_display_cart( $item_data, $cart_item ) {
    if ( empty( $cart_item['option-multi-trip-one-way'] ) ) {
        return $item_data;
    }
    $item_data[] = array(
        'key'     => __( 'Multi-trip/One-way **' ),
        'value'   => wc_clean( $cart_item['option-multi-trip-one-way'] ),
        'display' => '',
    );
    return $item_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'product_options_display_cart', 10, 2 );


/** Add custom fields to order. */
function product_options_to_order_items( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {   if ( empty( $values['option-multi-trip-one-way'] ) ) {
        return;   }    $item->add_meta_data( __( 'Multi-trip/One-way **' ), $values['option-multi-trip-one-way'] );}add_action( woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'product_options_to_order_items', 10, 4 );
```

http://prntscr.com/n42nig http://prntscr.com/n42nz0 http://prntscr.com/n42oj5

Comment: Based on this information its very unclear what you want to do, and what you have tried already. Please provide som code showing what you tried

Comment: hi @OutofOrbit I edited my topic, I think this one would help

Answer (score 0):

```
/**Output ACF in single product. */
function product_options_output_field() {
    $html = "";
    if( have_rows('select_options') ):
        $html .= "<div class='select-options'>";
        $html .= "<h4>Select Options</h4>";
        $html .= "<select class='option-multi-trip-one-way' id='option-multi-trip-one-way' name='option-multi-trip-one-way'>";
        $html .= "<option value='N/A'>Multi-trip/One-way **</option>";
        while( have_rows('select_options') ) : the_row();

            $multi_trip = get_sub_field('multi-tripone-way');
            $html .= "<option value=".$multi_trip.">".$multi_trip."</option>";

    endwhile;
    $html .= "</select>";

    $html .= "<br/>";

    $html .= "<select class='option-color' id='option-color' name='option-color'>";
    $html .= "<option value='N/A'>Color</option>";
        while( have_rows('select_options') ) : the_row();

            $color = get_sub_field('color');
            $html .= "<option value=".$color.">".$color."</option>";

        endwhile;
    $html .= "</select>";
    $html .= "</div>"; 
    endif;

    echo $html;

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'product_options_output_field', 10 );


/** * Add ACF to cart item. */
function product_options_add_to_cart_item( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {
    $option_multi_trip_one_way = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'option-multi-trip-one-way');
    $option_color = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'option-color');


    if ( empty( $option_multi_trip_one_way) || empty( $option_color)) {
        return $cart_item_data;  
    }

    $cart_item_data['option-multi-trip-one-way'] = $option_multi_trip_one_way;
    $cart_item_data['option-color'] = $option_color;

    return $cart_item_data;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'product_options_add_to_cart_item', 10, 3 );


/** Display ACF in the cart.*/
function product_options_display_cart( $item_data, $cart_item ) {
    if ( empty( $cart_item['option-multi-trip-one-way'] ) || empty( $cart_item['option-color'] )) {
        return $item_data;
    }

    $item_data[] = array(
        'key'     => __( 'Multi-trip/One-way **' ),
        'value'   => wc_clean( $cart_item['option-multi-trip-one-way'] ),
        'display' => '',
    );
    $item_data[] = array(
        'key'     => __( 'Color' ),
        'value'   => wc_clean( $cart_item['option-color'] ),
        'display' => '',
    );
    return $item_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'product_options_display_cart', 10, 2 );


/** Add ACF to order.*/
function product_options_to_order_items( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    if ( empty( $values['option-multi-trip-one-way'] ) || empty( $values['option-color'] )) {
        return;
    }

    $item->add_meta_data( __( 'Multi-trip/One-way **' ), $values['option-multi-trip-one-way'] );
    $item->add_meta_data( __( 'Color' ), $values['option-color'] );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'product_options_to_order_items', 10, 4 );
```